# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MPMediaPlayback'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I got this error message when trying to develop video player.

> /Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/SwiftVideoPlayer/SwiftVideoPlayer/ViewController.swift:12:1:
>   Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MPMediaPlayback'

My code

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, MPMediaPlayback { //error message here

    var isPreparedToPlay: Bool = true
    var currentPlaybackRate: Float = 0.0
    var currentPlaybackTime: NSTimeInterval = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func play() {

    }

    func pause() {

    }

    func stop() {

    }

    func prepareToPlay() {

    }

    func beginSeekingBackward() {

    }

    func beginSeekingForward() {

    }

    func endSeeking() {

    }

}
```

What am I missing here?

Source code: https://github.com/datomnurdin/SwiftVideoPlayer

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackTime